# Linq query brings back an unknown column exception

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to populate a list of objects from a MySql database using EF6. Unfortunately, it keeps throwing out with the following message: `MySqlException: Unknown column 'Extent1.AccountId' in 'where clause'`.

```
         var accountList = (from a in context.accounts
                           select new AccountModel()
                           {
                               AccountId = a.AccountId,
                               AccountProfile = new AccountProfileModel()
                               {
                                   AccountImage = (from aia in context.accountimageactivities
                                                   join ai in a.accountimages on aia.AccountImageId equals ai.AccountImageId
                                                   join i in context.images on ai.ImageId equals i.ImageId
                                                   orderby aia.EffectiveDate descending
                                                   select new AccountImageModel()
                                                   {
                                                       Image = i.ImageFile,
                                                       RecordState = RecordStateEnum.Original,
                                                   }).FirstOrDefault(),

                                   AccountVocation = (from ava in context.accountvocationactivities
                                                      join av in a.accountvocations on ava.AccountVocationId equals av.AccountVocationId
                                                      join v in context.vocations on av.VocationId equals v.VocationId
                                                      orderby ava.EffectiveDate descending
                                                      select new AccountVocationModel()
                                                      {
                                                          Description = v.Description,
                                                          RecordState = RecordStateEnum.Original,
                                                      }).FirstOrDefault()
                               }
                           }).ToList();
```

If I remove either one of the `AccountImage` or `AccountVocation` nested queries, then the query executes just fine. It only happens if I try populate two or more properties within the `AccountModel` object.

What am I doing wrong? To me, this seems just fine on the surface. I could just limit the properties, within this query and populate them later within a foreach loop but that's rather expensive. What am I missing here?

Comment: Is there any relationship between accounts, accountimageactivities and accountvocationactivities? From your current query, it seems the queries for AccountImage and AccountVocation didn't filter based on AccountId.

Comment: @YongShun no. there's no relationship between the two tables. The odd part is, if I remove them from the query, I get a NullReferenceException instead.

Comment: Wouldn't either of those tables relate back to Account??  It does seem odd that you would want to simply include the latest AccountImage.... and AccountVocation,.... without actually ensuring they are associated with the account in question, If these tables are related to Account then leverage navigation properties to Select them when populating the Account model rather than writing Linq-QL queries.